# Button back in my Webview cause output

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-webview, android-button

Very good at all.
I have a fragment is called a drawerlist. Within this fragment I have a webView showing a web page.
I can surf the web, but the problem comes when I want to return to the previous page, and pulse on the back button.
The result I get is that pressing the back button, the application closes. And what I want is to return to the previous page.

**Code fragment is as follows:**

```
public class BClasesWebViewFragment extends Fragment {


private WebView webView;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    WebSettings webSettings =  this.webView.getSettings (); 
    webSettings . setJavaScriptEnabled ( true ); 
    webSettings . setDomStorageEnabled ( true ); 
    this . webView . setWebViewClient ( new  WebViewClient ()); 
    this . webView . setWebChromeClient ( new  WebChromeClient ()); 
    webSettings . setLoadWithOverviewMode ( true );
    webSettings . setUseWideViewPort ( true );

    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");


    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
        }
    });     
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bclases_webview, container, false);
    webView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webViewBClases);
    return view;
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}


}
```

Thank you very much everyone.
I learned a lot on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

this will work perfectly.

Comment: Piyush Wooooooooooooooooow many thanks.
It has worked perfectly.